# iOS App: unrecognized selector sent to instance - Recording video AVFoundation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I keep getting the following error message from my developed app:

```
[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:recordingDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x190e10
```

The code for this is from the following button to record video:

```
- (IBAction)takeVideo {
    AVCaptureMovieFileOutput *movieFileOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *movieFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"something.mov"];
    NSString *mypath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:movieFileName];
    NSURL *outputURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:mypath];

    [self.captureSession addOutput:movieFileOutput];
    [movieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:outputURL recordingDelegate:self];
    [outputURL release];
}
```

What have I done wrong?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class probably does not implement all the required methods of the `AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate` protocol: specifically, you need to implement `captureOutput:didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:fromConnections:error:`

See the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).